# ssis - how import xml from database sql server to XML Source

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, ssis

I have XML in the database. 
I want to read the file and then save only the relevant columns.

The problem is that I cann't read the file and transfer only the columns.

I tried to make: 
On **data flow task** 
Contains: 
**XML Source**

But XML Source 
Can not import database  just from *file* or *variable* 
Is there another option?